# How to use VAE encoded feature to unsupervised anomaly detection

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm trying to implement VAE by replicating the methodology found in the paper "Unsupervised Anomaly Detection Using Variational Auto-Encoder based Feature Extraction". https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8819434 or here.

My question is in order to apply the encoded layer output to the unsupervised anomaly detections, how this was implemented? What I have so far is I save the h5 model after creating layers for the encoder. However when I load the model, there's a warning saying the model doesn't include the training part.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So the encoder outputs two vectors to parameterize the posterior distribution `q(z|x)` with a mean and (log) variance vector. They use the mean vector of this distribution as a low dimensional and compressed representation of the data input. This input is used to perform anomaly detection with more traditional methods that usually struggle with high dimensional inputs.

These traditional methods are all implemented by [pyod](https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Alternatively, you can also use [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html). However, I would recommend to check out the former package regardless since their doc strings
contain all the explanation you need to understand how the specific method is used for anomaly detection.

So, what you need to do is to train a VAE on the normal data of the system.
Then you use the mean vector of the encoder outputs as input for the other methods.

For the serialization to work correctly, you might need to overwrite `get_config` and `from_config` (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize)). However, it is difficult to say what is the problem without a concrete error message and the rough structure of your implementation.